# Get all relationship types of a node efficiently

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a node with a lot of neighbors (~1M). I would like to get a list of all relationship types of all the relations at this node (should be around 6 different types). Currently I am using

`match (n:Label {indexedProperty:"value"}) match (n)-[r]-() return distinct type(r)`

but this takes quite long (around 18 secs).

Is there a way to do this more efficiently in cypher ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

APOC procedures can help here, try using `apoc.node.relationship.types()`:

```
match (n:Label {indexedProperty:"value"})
return apoc.node.relationship.types() as types
```

That will get you a list of distinct types on the node.